# Why can't Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install on a computer with Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm faced with what seems to be the usual teething problem of installing Ubuntu on a windows 10 computer for those new to linux. I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Iso image) and created a bootable install USB. The installation process progresses normally until its time to install grub, which fails with the message ...  I have read several suggestions and have tried a dozen of them but to no avail. I have disabled secure boot, have tried to create partitions manually, but grub2 would not just install. Where am I missing it? Someone, please help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and ad details on what you are doing and what is the problem.

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Is the install failing at the grub install at the end of the install process? A few systems have locked ESP - efi system partition, check UEFI settings, some have corruption and need chkdsk (Windows) or dosfsck (Linux) on the ESP. Is Windows fast start up off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Its an acer (aspire 3). Let me check for the video card and come back on that... meantime, installation is failing at the end of the installation process. I m using usb. windows start up looks slow.

Comment: Sorry, oldfred, I misunderstood the last part  of of your comment.... I have turned off windows fast start now. I will try to implement the suggestions and  install Ubuntu again and see if I will succeed.

Comment: It appears that you omitted the critical information of *exactly what the error message was* Consider an [edit] to include this vital info.